# Creating Slider for showing multiple images

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am creating a slider using HTML, javascript, and CSS.
The problem I have it showing only the first two images (li) and not sliding to the other (li) elements.
I have the code of HTML as following:

```
<section id="cliens" class="cliens section-bg">
      <div class="container">

    <ul id="slider">
      <li>
          <div class="row" data-aos="zoom-in">
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-6 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
              <img src="assets/img/clients/client-1.png" class="img-fluid" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-6 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
              <img src="assets/img/clients/client-2.png" class="img-fluid" alt="">
            </div>
          </div>
      </li>
      <li>
          <div class="row" data-aos="zoom-in">
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-6 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
              <img src="assets/img/clients/client-1.png" class="img-fluid" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-6 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
              <img src="assets/img/clients/client-2.png" class="img-fluid" alt="">
            </div>
          </div>
      </li>
      <li>
          <div class="row" data-aos="zoom-in">
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-6 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
              <img src="assets/img/clients/client-1.png" class="img-fluid" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-6 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
              <img src="assets/img/clients/client-2.png" class="img-fluid" alt="">
            </div>
          </div>
      </li>
    </ul>

      </div>
    </section>
```

and the javascript code as following:

```
<script>
        // Slide every slideDelay seconds
        const slideDelay = 5000;

        const dynamicSlider = document.getElementById("slider").value;

        var curSlide = 0;
        window.setInterval(()=>{
          curSlide++;
          if (curSlide === dynamicSlider.childElementCount) {
            curSlide = 0;
          }

          // Actual slide
          dynamicSlider.firstElementChild.style.setProperty("margin-left", "-" + curSlide + "00%");
        }, slideDelay);

      </script>
```

and the CSS as following:

```
  <style>
        #slider {
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;

          margin: 0 auto;
          border: 10px solid transparent;
          padding: 0px;

          z-index: 100;
          overflow: hidden;
          white-space: nowrap;
          box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        #slider > li {
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;

          position: relative;
          display: inline-block;
          overflow: hidden;
          font-size: 15px;
          font-size: initial;
          line-height: normal;
          transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 1.3, 0.65, 1); /* Slide css animation */
          background-size: cover;
          vertical-align: top;
          box-sizing: border-box;
          white-space: normal;
        }
      </style>
```

Answer (score 1):

1: You are trying to get the value of `slider` but slider does not have any value.

2: You are trying to define a non css value in line 14 (margin-left -000% are trying to do what?)

3: I think you missed up some lines of code, cause this code even runs...

I know what you want to do, but you need to specify a higher `z-index` for `ul` and lowers for `li` then make a "animation" with the `li` changing its positions.

I made a very simple slider without any animation, you can use it in your code if you want.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <style> 
    #img
    { 
        transition: linear 2s; 
        width: 500px; 
        height: 500px; 
    }
    </style>
        <title>Page Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1448375240586-882707db888b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MXx8Zm9yZXN0fGVufDB8fDB8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" id="img">
        <script>
            var counter = 0;
var t; 
window.onload = function() {setInterval(change, 5000);}
function change()
{ 
    var imgs = ['https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1473448912268-2022ce9509d8?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1025&q=80', 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1519821172144-4f87d85de2a1?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1231&q=80', 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1448375240586-882707db888b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MXx8Zm9yZXN0fGVufDB8fDB8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60'];
if(counter === 3) 
{ counter = 0; }
else
{
 document.getElementById('img').src = imgs[0 + counter];
 counter++;
} 
}
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you fix these errors I can give you the entire answer.

Hope I helped!

Comment: If possible can you share that slider with me, meanwhile I will note down your notes and try to fix it.

Comment: Lol, I forgot to put the slider. I will update my answer, sorry.

Comment: @HashemHRamadan ok, I fixed